# How to Compute a Field in a Form from another Form or View in a Lotus DB

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have form "A" which there is a field that I need be computed after composed from Form "B".  The forms are in the same database.  I am not sure if it would be better to have the Form "A" field compute after composed from a "View" that uses the Form "B" or what would be the best way to get the field populated.
I have tried to do a @DBlookup, with no success.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Forms do not contain information, only documents do. Forms just represent information stored in documents.

Assume you have a view with name: "viewName" and it displays a set of documents.

The **first sorted column** of this view contains key values.

We want to get value of field someField by key from this view.

Create a new form, create a "Computed when composed" field and set the following formula as value:

```
@DbLookup("":"NoCache"; @DbName; "viewName"; "keyValue"; "someField");
```

It will access view "viewName" in the current database, get a document by "keyValue" and return value of field with name "someField"

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried to do a @DBlookup, with no success.

Well, what went wrong? Why didn't this work? When do you a `@DbLookup` call, you need to provide a view, a "key" and the field or view column you want to pull back from the matching document. Assuming you have a key with which you can link document A and document B, the look-up should be pretty straightforward.